# Accessing nested (In a list) information in DataTable in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny

So my current issue is creating a Shiny dashboard in R. While I've used Shiny and Plotly / Dash (Python) before I've never had to do this with renderDT and am unfamiliar with it. What the end goal is a table that I can click on the cell and it will show me an expanded version of the information present in the cell. Currently all the data is in a nested format / a list in the cell. How would I access the information within the cells for usage with both creating the display name (And not just saying [object Object] in the cell). I do have a specific reason why I need the data in a nested format as the data needs to be presented in a wide view frame based on a VPs request and we all know when a VP wants something they get it. Thanks in advance!

So far I've read large amounts of the reference docs but still can't seem to find a large enough set of information on renderDT and the javascript back end to answer my question.

Adding in a reproducible example as requested

```
nested_data <- tibble(
  rows = c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5"),
  columns = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"),
  name = c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5"),
  color = c("red", "blue", "orange", "purple", "black"),
  random_info = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
)

nested_data %<>% nest(data = !c(rows, columns)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = columns, values_from = data)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      nested_data
    )
  })
}
```

Here is the data frame I'm trying to work with as well. The information listed in name, color, random_info is just to show the nesting while at the end I'm hoping that I can make it show the name value where the nested data is and a hover over or click on where I can let people see all the relevant information.

```
rows  c1               c2               c3               c4               c5              
  <chr> <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>          
1 r1    <tibble [1 × 3]> <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>          
2 r2    <NULL>           <tibble [1 × 3]> <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>          
3 r3    <NULL>           <NULL>           <tibble [1 × 3]> <NULL>           <NULL>          
4 r4    <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>           <tibble [1 × 3]> <NULL>          
5 r5    <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>           <tibble [1 × 3]>
```

Comment: Bump, please don't beat me mods for bumping